# Numerical pitfalls without extended precision FPUs

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, numerical, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

Monniaux's excellent article, ["The Pitfalls of Verifying Floating Point Arithmetic"](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/28/14/29/PDF/floating-point-article.pdf), gives examples of unexpected numerical behavior. However, most of the examples depend on extended precision FPUs or extended precision operations (e.g. multiply-accumulate). Besides signed zero and comparisons involving NaN are there any good examples of surprising numerical behavior when extend precision hardware is disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example that is often surprising to programmers is when `x + 1 == x`.  In single precision floating point, this is true for `x` as small as `2^25` because of the limited precision of the mantissa.  This often comes up when incrementing time values in a simulation by a small timestep.  A [similar problem](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/455.f96/disasters.html) affected the Patriot missile.

Comment: Yes, good example. I would point out that this loss of precision occurs for any two numbers with different exponents: Complete absorption of one of the terms occurs when the exponents are of sufficiently different magnitude.